# How to get names of users by id in a v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to print the names of users into the UI, but it is coming up empty.

Codesandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/add-poc-xznwe?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FEditPost.vue&theme=dark
***(click POSTS --> EDIT (Acme Widget) and I am trying to get user names to show up under "Current Contacts")***

Let me explain:

I have a single file component `EditPost.vue` that contains a `posts` object with data like so:

```
posts: [
        {
          post_id: 1,
          process_id: 4,
          post_name: "ACME Widget",
          poc_list: [1, 2]
        },
        {
          post_id: 2,
          process_id: 1,
          post_name: "XYZ Widget",
          poc_list: [3]
        },
```

The `poc_list` property contains the user ids of people associated with a particular post.

There is also a `userProfiles` object that contains the names of each user with their user id, like so:

```
userProfiles: [
        {
          uid: 1,
          firstname: "Claiborne",
          lastname: "Heberden",
          email: "cheberden0@gravatar.com"
        },
        {
          uid: 2,
          firstname: "Gerick",
          lastname: "Tetla",
          email: "gtetla1@whitehouse.gov"
        },
```

How can I display the user's firstname in a `v-for` loop?

Here's what I tried:

`EditPost.vue` template:

```
        <ul v-if="$route.params.poc_list">
          <li v-for="poc in contacts" :key="poc.uid">{{poc}}</li>
        </ul>
```

`EditPost.vue` script section:

```
 methods: {
    contacts() {
      const contact = this.userProfiles.filter(
        poc => this.posts.poc_list === poc.uid
      );
      return contact.firstname;
    },
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your `poc_list` is of type array and in the `contacts` method you are comparing an array with the `uid`.

Comment: @VidhyutPandya OK, how would I fix?

Comment: @redshift You would loop through the `posts` array and search in the individual `poc_list` item, and see if any of them [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the `poc.uid` the list is being filtered with.

Comment: @YomS. Can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through your post object, when you get to the post.poc_list loop. for every item in the poc_list, 
you do a find in the userProfiles list with the uid and return the firstname

```
<div v-for="post in posts">
    {{post.post_name}}
    <div v-for="item in post.poc_list">
        {{ userProfiles.find(x => x.uid === item).firstname || '' }}
    </div>
</div>
```

in your sandbox prototype

```
<ul v-if="$route.params.poc_list">
    <li v-for="(poc, index) in $route.params.poc_list" :key="index">
        {{ userProfiles.find(x => x.uid === poc).firstname || '' }}
    </li>
</ul>
```